# Databinding ListBox to a List of a Class that Contains an Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have a list of items of a custom class.  That class contains an observable collection of another class, that has two string values.  I want to data bind to one of the string values, based on the other one.  So as a fictitious example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}
public class Pet
{
    public string AnimalType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I then bind the list box to a list of Person:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
Person p = new Person() { Name = "Joe", Pets = new ObservableCollection<Pet>() { new Pet() { Name = "Spot", AnimalType = "Dog" }, new Pet() { Name = "Whiskers", AnimalType = "Cat" } } };
people.Add(p);
p = new Person() { Name = "Jim", Pets = new ObservableCollection<Pet>() { new Pet() { Name = "Juniper", AnimalType = "Cat" }, new Pet() { Name = "Butch", AnimalType = "Dog" } } };
people.Add(p);
p = new Person() { Name = "Jane", Pets = new ObservableCollection<Pet>() { new Pet() { Name = "Tiny", AnimalType = "Dog" }, new Pet() { Name = "Tulip", AnimalType = "Cat" } } };
people.Add(p);
MyListBox.ItemsSource = people;
```

I want to bind the name of the person and a pet name, if the animal type is Dog.  I know I can do bind using an indexer, but I specifically need the dog entry, even if it is the second entry in the pet collection. The XAML below works for displaying the first item in the collection, but for the second item in the list it is wrong because the dog is the second item in the colelction:

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="55.015" Width="302.996">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Height="25.015" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Pets[0].Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Can anyone provide some direction on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a value converter to show dogs only.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Pets, Converter={StaticResource FindDogConverter}}" />
```

Code behind:

```
public class FindDogConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IEnumerable<Pet> pets = value as IEnumerable<Pet>;
        return pets.Single(p => p.AnimalType == "Dog").Name;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I can use the converter parameter to keep it generic, so this is exactly what I needed.